# How many states are possible for two (indistinguishable) electrons with $n=2$ in an atom if we forget Pauli’s exclusion principle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, atoms, orbitals, quantum-states, pauli-exclusion-principle

I have been told I can use $^8C_2 = 28$ to obtain the answer to this question, but I am doubtful of this result since I obtain $21$ by simply writing out the possible states as ($ml_{1}$, $ms_{1}$, $ml_{2}$,$ms_{2}$). Is there a formula that I can use to find the answer to this question??

Comment: Why use $^8C_{\ 2}$? 21 states seems correct and 28 seems too much. There is no formula as such. Have you written out each possible state, 15 in total, then the additional ones, 6 (for a total of 21 states) when the exclusion principle does not apply?

Comment: What does it mean to have indistinguishable electrons without the Pauli exclusion principle?

Comment: @josephh The explanation was that the degenerate levels are 2n^2. So the answer would be 8 states for l=0 and 8C2 for l=1 giving in total 36 states without including Pauli’s principle. Sorry for the error in my question.

Comment: @Andrew the second part of the same question asks for the number of states including Paulis exclusion.

Comment: @JetBlakh No, it's not that straight forward. You need to write out each individual state and you'll count 15. Removing the PEP and you gain another 6. Andrew, photons/bosons are indistinguishable too and the PEP does not apply.